# Eclipse IDE Screen Recording Using XBox Game Bar on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, eclipse, xbox-game-dvr

Using Eclipse IDE means many modals windows will appear (classes creator, preferences, ...).

When I use XBox Game Bar, only Eclipse main window is recorded, the rest is invisible.

Same applies to Notepad ++ (e.g View -> Summary).

Is there a way to include everything related to Eclipse in the recording?